# Answering Phone

Tags: telephone-conversation

My Prof said his sister in law answers the phone with yabada/ yabadah. I'm not a German speaker but I figure that 'Ya' makes sense as yes but the following doesn't make sense to me. Could someone please clarify if this is indeed a thing German speakers do (In a certain region) or is it just a weird unique case thing.

Comment: It’s not a German word if that’s what you are asking, and it’s not a common way to answer the phone. Most people either say their name or a greeting, or a combination (“Schmidt, guten Tag”).

Comment: Flintstones yabadabadoo.

Comment: My best guess: _Ja, bin da!_ ‘Yes, I’m here!’

Comment: @chirlu Not to forget those who jokedly answer ‘Kriminalpolizei Weilheim!’, or ‘Krematorium Kempten?’ ;)

Comment: No relation to german language.

Answer (score 4):

Some people answer their phone with “Ja, bitte?”, which directly tranlates to “Yes, please?” I think this is what your prof meant.

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works.